# プロトコルの使いどころ

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, delegate

iOSのプロトコルについてよくわからない点があるので質問させていただきたいです。
まずプロトコルの使いどころですが、プロトコルは主に「デリゲートを実現するため」に使われるのでしょうか？
デリゲート実現以外の使われ方はほとんどされないでしょうか？
他に思いつく使いどころは「機能を共通化できるのでポリモーフィズムが使える」、「他の人が自分のコードを見た時にクラスがどういう設計かを把握しやすくする」などでしょうか？
「他の人が自分のコードを見た時にクラスがどういう設計かを把握しやすくする」ためにプロトコルを使うなら個人開発ではそういった視点でプロトコルを使うことはないでしょうか？（そもそも1か月後の自分がコードを見た時に理解しやすいようになるべく個人開発でもプロトコルは使ったほうがいい？）

プロトコル指向プログラミングといった概念を知り、プロトコルを使ってプログラミングをしていきたいのですが、ほとんどプロトコルを使う機会がありません。どういった時にプロトコルを使っていけばいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Objective-CのProtocolと、SwiftのProtocolは別物です。
で、SwiftのProtocolについて、情報を探してみると……

[Swift 2で提唱されているProtocol Oriented ProgrammingをWWDCセッションから学ぶ](http://qiita.com/mono0926/items/bb52e657df6978713334)

[Swift では Protocol を積極的に使おう](http://qiita.com/mokumoku/items/2744c68fdb4bb53d0376)

クラスではなく、構造体を使う。プロトコルとプロトコルのExtensionで、クラスの継承と同等のことができる。などなど。
Swift 2以降という条件ですが、腰を据えて勉強する価値がありそうだという印象を、私は持っています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
objective-cのプロトコルとswiftのプロトコルは別物なのですね。
構造体とプロトコルを使ってswiftを書いていくということに僕も興味を持っています。
swiftのプロトコルを理解するためにprotocol extensionについても調べてみようと思います。